# Okta Authentication integration with my application is successfully running in apache tomcat but not in IBM Websphere 8.5.5.15

Tags: websphere, saml, okta

Okta Authentication integration with my application is successfully running in apache tomcat but not in IBM Websphere 8.5.5.15 . It is redirecting me to the error page.

It's working in the Apache Tomcat. Do I need to add some extra configuration. I have generated Keystore as like as I generated for Tomcat. Do I need to do any extra configuration for Websphere Application Server ?

Attaching log :

> Error retrieving metadata from https://wyndham.okta.com/app/exk1fbbf0r3dV7jIk1d8/sso/saml/metadata 
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version 
>   
> at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:32) ~[na:8.0 build_20181010] 
>   
> at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:37) ~[na:8.0 build_20181010]

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't post updates in comments

Comment: You need to enable ssl tracing. Probably system that you are trying to connect is using unsecure, old SSL protocols, not supported by default by WebSphere. You didnt write which Java are you using on Tomcat, as in WAS .15 it is Java 8, which has stronger security settings.